# How to pipe exception.what() detail from cerr into logging macro

Tags: c++, macros

I'm attempting to serialize XML data using a schema validator in C++. I'm getting an error message. I can report the message like this:

```
std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
```

Returns:

*'error parsing: unable to validate schema'*

However, when I do this:

```
std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
```

I get a substantially more detailed report including specific parsing errors. I would like to pipe the output reported to `cerr` to a variable for logging, but I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

The exception class I'm using is actually a `typedef` custom XSD parse exception. The exception is **not** a `std::exception` type. I'm wondering if the authors of the XSD code overloaded the `<<` operator to provide different outputs depending on the `ostream` type. Does this make sense? I've never seen that before.

Comment: You should check the function(s) called by the macro, as it might be a problem with them instead? Maybe they can't handle possible newlines in string arguments?

Comment: The macro has the same output as `std::cout`. The error message from the exception appears different depending on the output buffer.

Comment: @TylerJandreau: `exception.what()` returns the same value regardless of what you do with that value, how is it supposed to know what the caller is doing?

Comment: @GManNickG I know. The `exception` is actually a `typedef` class. I'm wondering if the author somehow overloaded the `<<` operator to have different outputs depending on the input `ostream`. Original question edited.

Comment: So what's the return type of `what()`?

Comment: @KennyTM `const char*`

Comment: Then I see no reason the two statements will print different results, unless ERROR is only printing the first line.

Comment: @KennyTM Neither do I. My `ERROR` macro and `std::cout` have the same output. This is vexing. While it's not a show stopper, it's annoying.

Comment: Have you tried `#define ERROR(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)`?

Comment: @KennyTM That's exactly the macro I'm using.

Comment: @TylerJandreau: You need to stop assuming there's some magic overloading going on. As both Kenny and I have said, it doesn't matter what type `exception` has, it matters what `exception.what()` returns and it returns a `const char*`. The value of that is the **same** independent of what you do with that; the source of your confusion lies somewhere in the implementation of `ERROR`, as it's the only thing that can possibly do something  *different* than `std::cout`. Show us more code.

Comment: In other words, this is no different than `foo(exception.what())` and `bar(exception.what())`. Don't let the syntax confuse you (macro and `operator<<`), it ultimately comes down to what you do with the value.

Comment: @GManNickG There is no need to be condescending. The behaviour between `std::cout` and `std::cerr` is different. End of story. If it wasn't, I wouldn't have asked this question.